# Python MySQLdb query to search multiple partial keywords

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I'm pretty new with python and sql and i'm so confused right now with a query problem, some help will be appreciated.

What i've: I've a function who looks for coincidences of text input on MySQL table.

PD: I'm loading the DB conection on another file with MySQLdb

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Config.DBConfig import *
class SomeClass:
    def Search(self):
        Fruit = 'App'
        cur.execute("SELECT reference,name FROM fruits WHERE name LIKE '%%%s%%'" % (Fruit))
        row = cur.fetchall()
        print row
Test = SomeClass()
Test.Search()
```

And it returns the correct output:

```
001 , Apples are red
002 , apples
004 , Green APPLES
```

But now i want to do the same with 2 or more keywords on the same text input field and it must return the fruits ( reference and name ) who has those partial keywords on the fruit name ( both keywords ), for example:

```
input = 'App re'
output:
001 , Apples are red
004 , Green Apples
```

I can't figure how i can concatenate those input keywords with SQL LIKEs or maybe i'm looking for the wrong method ( almost for sure ).

Need some help or guidance or tip plz

Thx to everybody.

EDIT:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Config.DBConfig import *
class SomeClass:
    def Search(self):
        Fruit = 'App re'
        word1, word2 = Fruit.split()
        cur.execute("SELECT reference,name FROM fruits WHERE name LIKE ('%%%s%%') UNION SELECT reference,name FROM fruits WHERE name LIKE ('%%%s%%')" % (word1, word2))
        row = cur.fetchall()
        print row
```

It's not exactly what i need ( i only want those results who has the 2 words ) but i'm approaching to the desired result.

EDIT 2:

Finally achieved what i wanted ( probably in a bad way, but it works ):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Config.DBConfig import *
class SomeClass:
    def Search(self):
        Fruit = input_some_text
        if len(Fruit.split()) == 1:
            cur.execute("SELECT reference,name FROM fruits WHERE name LIKE ('%%%s%%')" % (Fruit))
            row = cur.fetchall()
            for result in row:
                print result
        if len(Fruit.split()) == 2:
            word1, word2 = Fruit.split()
            id1 = cur.execute("SELECT reference,name FROM fruits WHERE name LIKE ('%%%s%%')" % (word1))
            row1 = cur.fetchall()
            id2 = cur.execute("SELECT reference,name FROM fruits WHERE name LIKE ('%%%s%%')" % (word2))
            row2 = cur.fetchall()
            final = set(row1) & set(row2)
            print list(final)
        if len(Fruit.split()) == 3:
            word1, word2, word3 = supplierName.split()
            id1 = cur.execute("SELECT reference,name FROM fruits WHERE name LIKE ('%%%s%%')" % (word1))
            row1 = cur.fetchall()
            id2 = cur.execute("SELECT reference,name FROM fruits WHERE name LIKE ('%%%s%%')" % (word2))
            row2 = cur.fetchall()
            id3 = cur.execute("SELECT reference,name FROM fruits WHERE name LIKE ('%%%s%%')" % (word3))
            row3 = cur.fetchall()
            final = set(row1) & set(row2) & set(row3)
            result = list(final)
            print result
```

Comment: Is there a performance reason that you can't do this across the set of rows within python, i.e., the number of rows is **very** large? One could just pull the rows into python and do the multiple param search in python.

Comment: There're 20k+ rows on that table, pretty much heavy ( and there're more tables being readed or modified and they're even bigger ). Do you mean load the rows into a var and split the input for search the results ? ( sry if its not that what do you mean, i'm pretty new )

Comment: well, 20K rows is pretty small in general. If you're dealing on transfers on the server, and you are not starved on memory, then that's pretty negligible. However, if you want to go work it out in SQL, you can consider using `locate` to build a procedure that checks a vector of strings to search for.